# Game real-time modification utility?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Well, I don't know how native English call it, in China, we call it "游戏克星". Something like *Game buster*, *Game master*, *FPE (Fix People Expert)*, etc. But they only run in Win32.

It should be capable of:

- Analyze memory to find out which bytes are used by life-point, energy-point, etc., and change them (when the game is running).
- Save/Restore memory snapshot, so I can resume the game at any time. (Most games only allow you to save at specific save point)

Comment: a Cheat tool that scans the RAM ? to make trainers,etc.?

Comment: @Uri: Yes, scan the RAM and do diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Scanmem](http://taviso.decsystem.org/scanmem.html)

scanmem is a simple interactive debugging utility for linux, used to locate the address of a variable in an executing process. This can be used for the analysis or modification of a hostile process on a compromised machine, reverse engineering, or as a "pokefinder" to cheat at video games.

**Features**

- Interactive command mode, with online
  help.
- Specify target value exactly, or
  using abstract "higher" and "lower".
- Supports variable width targets.
- Set variable to any value.
- Modify variables once, or continually
  over user specified period.
- Detailed information about mappings,
  allow users to eliminate regions.

[image: Scanmem]

### [Game Cheater](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gamecheater/)

It is a game cheater for GNU/Linux , use "ptrace" system call. With it, you can search and edit the game process' memory, modify HP, MP, score .

[image: Game Cheater]